# Could I change row before saving Laravel Excel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I use Laravel Excel.

The code builds excel file and does export to  path `$path.$filename`:

```
  Excel::store(new VisitorsExport($request), $path.$filename);
```

Could I iterate all rows before `Excel::store`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `WithMapping` to your export so you can define a `map()` function that accept a row and return an array, so you can iterate and trasform all of your rows, this is an example with the Eloquent query builder:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class VisitorsExport implements FromQuery, WithMapping
{    

    public function map($visitor): array
    {
        return [
            $visitor->id,
            $visitor->name,
            Date::dateTimeToExcel($visitor->created_at),
        ];
    }
}
```

You can read the complete docs on mapping [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html).

Comment: I need styling not mapping, could you explain how to style rows/cell before exporting

Comment: You asked to iterate over all rows and map is an iterator, if your need was styling please update your question, as written your needs are not clear